# Binding MySQL to local port over SSH - works in console, not via PHP shell_exec() in Mac OSX

Tags: php, mysql, macos, bash, ssh

I am running OSX 10.6.7 and trying to connect to a remote MySQL server via ssh to run some PHP scripts. Currently, I run the following commands with no problem:

```
ssh -i /Users/xxxx/key.pem user@data.server.com -L 53306:localhost:3306 -f sleep 60 >> logfile
mysql -u user -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 53306
```

After I authenticate with a password, it works perfectly. (So long as it's before the sleep timeout, of course.)

When I run this PHP script, however...

```
$shell = shell_exec("ssh -i /Users/xxxx/key1.pem user@data.server.com -L 53306:localhost:3306 -f sleep 60 >> logfile");

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'password', 'database', 53306);
```

I get connection refused. When I omit the shell_exec(), I get the same error. When I echo $shell, nothing is outputted.

key1.pem has chmod 400 permission, is a copy of the key.pem, and I ran chown _www on it. I get the same errors if I try to use key.pem or key1.pem. I also tried 440 permissions as well with no luck.

Thanks for the help; this is driving me nuts.

Comment: The script seems to run for me if i run it from the console.  Is it running under a different user?  Maybe ssh is not starting because of a permissions issue.  Try using the system($cmd, $return) and see if the return value is giving you anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need a password if you're using a private key? Do you mean a password for the key file? I think it could be the problem because ssh accept authentication using passwords only in tty and php *exec functions hasn't it.

For the sleep question you can try the `-N` option of ssh, which is useful for tunnels and it doesn't require a remote command to be executed. Try to establish a tunnel using the shell and then simply connect to that tunnel with php.

Update:

I tried this and it does work on my Mac

```
<?
exec('ssh -f -N -n -L 5500:localhost:3306 your-host-name &> /dev/null');
var_dump(mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:5500', 'root'));
```

you should add your -i option and replace your hostname.

This is the output on my computer

```
resource(9) of type (mysql link)
```

But keep in mind that you'll have a couple of problems with this. The `&> /dev/null` statement makes the exec function return immediately, but it will suppress any output (mostly errors) when you execute the script multiple times, because every new request will try to open a new connection, it will succeed but it cannot setup the tunnel because port 5500 is already in use. After a while you'll have a lot of ssh process pending on your machine.

To avoid this you should try to connect to mysql before the ssh call and if you can't then setup the tunnel and redo the mysql connect call. In this way you can solve the problem.

Comment: The password is for the MySQL server, not for the ssh connection (that is passwordless). I don't own the MySQL server, so I can't make any changes to it.

Comment: Also your answer is a bit unclear to me. What do you mean by establish a tunnel using the shell and connect to it via PHP? shell_exec() should handle this.

Comment: In that case, this is not the problem. You can still try to open (and leave it open) the tunnel from the shell and try to login to the mysql server using only php (i.e. comment the shell_exec line on your code, and try in that way)

Comment: That works, but that's not a long-term solution. I don't want to have to open a shell manually to run my applications. Now to find out what the issue is with shell_exec(), I suppose...

Comment: Neither opening a tunnel in that way is a good long term solution. If you find the issue with the shell_exec (I'm still think that is something related to ssh and tty), you'll have to close the connection and in that way you simply can't. You have to wait 60 seconds to make the next request, or it will fail because port 53306 is already in use. You can look at this extension http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php I never tried that, but it seems that you have full control over the connection.

Comment: You may need the password of the key file, THAT is generally what the password is for.  This allows you to have one key, one password.  The only reason you wouldn't need a password is if you left your private key unlocked (terrible thing to do)

Comment: You said that your ssh connection is passwordless, don't you? You need that line only to setup the ssh tunnel, and then you can connect using mysql, with your password in the mysqli_connect call. I'm gonna update the answer with the full (two lines) script.

Comment: Yes, it is. I was responding to @Jeremy Walton.

Comment: have you also tried putting a "&" at the end of the ssh command?

Comment: The & alone doesn't work unless you redirect output (both stdout and stderr) on /dev/null, exec function will wait for command end.

Comment: Guess I shall accept this answer since it did get me somewhere and no one else seems to want to chime in!