# Is there a way to connect MySQL with binding local port?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on detect(ip:port) the login behavior of MySQL on different client, But I only get one client machine to use, what I want is to use the **same** *IP* and **various**(explicitly specific, not random select) *PORT* to connect the MySQL server, because you can specific a port to `bind` in your client code.

Is there a way(On command line `mysql` or MySQL C API) to specific the port number on connecting the MySQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
ssh -i /Users/xxxx/key.pem user@data.server.com -L 53306:localhost:3306 -f sleep 60 >> logfile
mysql -u user -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 53306
```

Comment: Could you give more explanation?

Comment: Please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541688/binding-mysql-to-local-port-over-ssh-works-in-console-not-via-php-shell-exec